# Select2 nested json parsing not working Rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery, jquery-select2

I'm trying to make select2 working with my ajax loaded json data with nested attributes.
I wanna get something like this http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/#multi.

#### eaxmple json:

```
[{
  id: 1,
  name: "GroupName",
  users: [{id: 1, name: 'UserName'}, {id: 2, name: 'SecondUser}]
 }]
```

On the site they use `<optgroup label="GroupName"><option value="1">UserName</opyion></optgroup>` and getting the right result.

In my case it displays nesting properly, but I can select only `GroupName`, but I need to select nested `userName` and make `GrouoName` unselectable, only gor informational purposes.

#### code:

```
$('#user_tokens').select2({
  placeholder: "Search for a user",
  minimumInputLength: 0,
  tags: true,
  multiple: true,
  ajax: {
    url: "messages/users_data.json",
    dataType: 'json',
    quietMillis: 100,
    data:  function(search, page) {
      return {
        q: search,
        per: 3,
        page: page
      };
    },
    results: function(data, page) {
      return { 
        results: data,
         };
    }
  },
  formatResult: formatResult,
  formatSelection: formatSelection,
  dropdownCssClass: "bigdrop"
});
```

#### formatResult:

```
   var formatUserResult = function(data) {
     var optgroup = "";
     var users = "";
       if (data.name !== undefined) {
         data.users.forEach(function(e) {
           users += "<li class='select2-results-dept-1 select2-result select2-result-    selectable'>" + 
           "<div class='select2-result-label'>" +
             "<span class='select2-match'></span>"+
             e.firstname +
           "</div>" +
         "</li>";
         });
         optgroup += "<div class='select2-result-label'>" + 
         "<span class='select2-match'></span>" + 
         data.name + "</div>" +
         '<ul class="select2-result-sub">' + users + '</ul>';
       }
       return optgroup;
     }
```

The problem is that optgroup must have `class: 'select2-result-unselectable'`
Dunno what to do with it.

Comment: It seems like you're attempting to create select items manually. Any reason why? Can't you just have your JSON service return a structure like in the "Example Hierarchical Data" [here in the docs](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/#doc-query) and let the library take care of creating its internal stuff? As far as I understand it, `formatXxx()` functions are meant to create *labels* for the select items, not the actual items.

Comment: Or, if you don't want to change your service, have the uh... `results()` function (I think) in the `ajax` parameter massage it into that form, like in [the example for "Loading Data"](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/#data)